# how can I pass two list in one adapter?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to create cv app in my RecyclerViewdadapter class I want to pass list and one from model class I already passed and second one for dummy data. I am following this  stackoverflow link [Two ArrayList one RecyclerView Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450466/two-arraylist-one-recyclerview-adapter)

I want to achieve that this ui

[image: ui I want]

second current screenshot

[image: current UI]

below MyAdapter class

```
public class EducationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    final int Internet_TYPE = 0;
    final int Dummy_TYPE = 1;
    public List<Education> educationList;
    public Context context;
    public List<FakeData> fakeData;
    public int[] subjectImage;
    public String[] subjectText;

    public EducationAdapter(List<Education> educationList, Context context, List<FakeData> fakeData, int[] subjectImage, String[] subjectText) {
        this.educationList = educationList;
        this.context = context;
        this.fakeData = fakeData;
        this.subjectImage = subjectImage;
        this.subjectText = subjectText;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EducationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == Internet_TYPE) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.education_item, parent, false);  // change


            return new EducationAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        if (viewType == Dummy_TYPE) {
            return new ViewHolder.FakeViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EducationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            Education education = educationList.get(position);
            holder.duration.setText(education.getDuration());
            holder.degree.setText(education.getDegree());
            holder.institution.setText(education.getInstitution());

        }
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder.FakeViewHolder) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return educationList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView duration, institution, degree, educationInfo, subjects, computers_science;
        ;
        private ImageView educationImage, subjectImage, computerScience;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            institution = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.institution);
            degree = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.degree);
            educationImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.educationImage);
            educationInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.education_info);
            subjectImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjectImage);
            subjects = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjects);


        }

        public class FakeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView item;
            public ImageView icon;

            public FakeViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                item = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            }

            public void populate(FakeData fakeDatas) {
                item.setText(fakeDatas.getImage());
                icon.set
                dataSnippet.setText(imageDataWrapper.getPage_Desc());
                Picasso.with(context).load(imageDataWrapper.getPage_ImageThumb()).into(image);
            }

        }
    }
}

below my EducationItem where I have implemented network call and dummy data

public class EducationItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EducationAdapter educationAdapter;
    public List<Education> educationList;
    public List<FakeData> fakeData;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.education);


       final  int [] subjectImage = {R.drawable.computer_science,
                R.drawable.data_structure,

        };




        final String[] subjectText = {
                "Computer Science",
                "Data Structure",

        };

    KitabInterface kitabInterface = ApiClient.getApiService();
    Call<KitabSawti> call = kitabInterface.getEducation();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<KitabSawti>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<KitabSawti> call, Response<KitabSawti> response) {
            educationList=  response.body().getEducation();
            RecyclerView recyclerView  =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            educationAdapter = new EducationAdapter(educationList, EducationItem.this, fakeData, subjectImage, subjectText); // changes
            recyclerView.setAdapter(educationAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<KitabSawti> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

below educution_item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBlust"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/educationImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/education_information"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/education_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/education_information"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_duration"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/institution"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_institution"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_degree"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subjectImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/university_subjects"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subjects"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:text="@string/university_subjects"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/subject_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/subjects"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

below subjectList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlust"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/computers_science"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join two list in one list containing all items. Handling two different list in one adapter could make many different problems.

```
private void setAdapter() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new EducationItem());
    items.add(new FakeItem());
    recycler.setAdapter(newAdapter(items));
}

public interface Item {}

class EducationItem implements Item {
    //...fields
}

class FakeItem implements Item {
    //...fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marek said, you should join two list into one. Treat `Education` and `FakeData` as the same data type.

Using this approach, you should also override the `getViewType` method to indicate the `ViewType` of the item, so that the `onCreateViewHolder` can receive the `ViewType` you defined.